# Ошибка переменных в хранимой процедуре MySql

Tags: процедуры, переменные, mysql

Добрый день! Написал вот такую простенькую процедуру и на выходе получил ошибку "Table 'registr.table_ach' doesn't exist". Как я понял при вызове функции не передаются значения переменным. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Спасибо!
Вот сам код:

```
include_once("bd.php");
$query="CREATE PROCEDURE `main`(IN id INT, IN id1 INT, IN table_ach VARCHAR(255), IN    table_ach1 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT 'expert_titul' FROM  `table_ach` WHERE id = 'id';
IF expert_titul='I' THEN
UPDATE `table_ach1` SET `exp_choice` = `exp_choice` + 1 WHERE `id` = 'id1';
END IF;
END";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$query="CALL main('500000','29','achiev_man','achiev_girl');";
$res = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: Не понял, table_ach - это таблица или параметр процедуры? Впрочем, не знаю синтаксиса MySQL, так что это вопрос профана :-). И где INTO в Вашем запросе SELECT и переменная для хранения результата этого запроса? Думаю, что ошибку Вы получили не "на выходе", а на стадии разбора.

Comment: это параметр процедуры, в которой он является названием таблицы

Comment: Ну говорит, что нет у Вас таблицы table_ach в registr.

Comment: спасибо, это я понял. Дело в том, что table_ach это переменная в процедуре, которая должна передавать название таблицы, но она не передает почему-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в процедуре связана с тем, что `mysql` не знает о ваших намерениях. `mysql` считает, что запросом

```
SELECT 'expert_titul' FROM  `table_ach` WHERE id = 'id';
```

вы пытаетесь выбрать строку "expert_titul" из таблицы table_ach.

Для того, чтобы сообщить `mysql` что вы хотите выбирать из таблицы, указанной в переменной `table_ach`, достаточно выполнить следующее:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT expert_titul INTO @my_param FROM ", table_ach, " WHERE id = ?");
SET @id = id; 
PREPARE stmp FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmp USING @id;
```

Тогда выборка будет проходить по той таблице, которую мы указали в параметре `table_ach`, а полученное значение будет доступно через `@my_param`